# Hash URL on pageload in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

I really hope to find a solution here.
Need to load specific elements highlighted first on the pages based on url hash.
I have already set up "click" and "hover" functions for these elements. But also need these elements highlighted based on url. What selector should I use?

Basically I need the following scenario to be implemented:

```
if https://mypage.com#case1 loads
do this

if https://mypage.com#case2 loads
do this
```

Comment: so read `window.location.hash`.... Unsure what a "selector" has to do with this.  Are you reinventing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can get the URL and do a simple if else statement where you load what you need to based on the URL string.

It could be something like this:

```
var url = window.location.href; //get url string
if(url == "https://mypage.com#case1"){
    //run your case1 code
}else if(url == "https://mypage.com#case2"){
    //run your case2 code
}
```

I'm not sure what your use case is, but you probably want to parse the URL to get the relevant piece or parameter you are looking for.